# includes assertion in playwright for for CSS and Attribute?

Tags: typescript, ui-automation, playwright, assertion, browser-automation

Here I have a piece of code in Playwright with the ToHaveCSS function which returns the exact value of the mentioned CSS.
Locator:

```
locator('//label[text()=\'Chat Status\']/following-sibling::*/button')
       Expected string: "rgb(40, 176, 131)"
       Received string: "rgb(40, 176, 131) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box"
```

As you can see the expected value matches the received value with some extra strings.

Is there any function like **string.includes**? Which can pass this test. I just want to validate the colour and the other stuff I don't need it. I can still copy and paste the received value to the expected string to pass it. But what if the value dynamically changes and I only want to validate the color? Are there any functions for the playwright to do this?

Comment: Can you share your test case?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of inbuilt [toHaveCss](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-css) method from `expect`:

> **toHaveCSS**
> Added in: v1.20
> Ensures the Locator resolves to an element with the given computed CSS   style.

Example:

`await expect(locator).toHaveCSS('display', 'flex');`

Here, this method will only assert the display value against the expected string 'flex'.

In my sample test using the above `toHaveCss`, I have something similar as yours (I am not sure why in your case the actual string has other values)

Here is my sample test assertion for background colour that works fine:

```html
test("Check background colour", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com");
  expect(page.getByText("A/B Testing")).toHaveCSS("color", "rgb(43, 166, 203)");
});
```

You can create a **helper method** for this expectation(remember to use `expect`) and pass any CSS property name and expected value for assertion.

Comment: I understand that CSS color returns 'RGB (43, 166, 203)'. What I'm asking is If the value is 'RGB (43, 166, 203)-some_random_string' and only want to validate the RGB. What can be done here. So I'm asking if there are functions like includes. String.includes() returns true. Like this.